# a routes is clean and could not return them in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, https

, I have a project in Laravel , and I have been upload it in my domain , everything going well, but in now I have a big trouble issue , the issue is all pages give me this messages :
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IjXZ.png) image , that told me : **Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**
I don't have an idea how this issue get , but I think because I delete index.php file and put a new one , that is from flutter , however , I return the original index.php file , and the issue still show .
**note** the index.php page is work , but the API routers didn't work.

Comment: Are you pointing your webserver to the public folder?

Comment: You should check your  `.htaccess` file is still present in your public folder as well.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: @Second2None where can I get the .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your default `.htaccess` file, which should be included in the public folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```